# EF core join in include

Tags: .net, entity-framework, lambda

I have an entity, "step" which has properties like "name", "description" and a list of "parameterValue" objects. A "parameterValue" object has properties like "parameterId" and "value".

I also have an entity "parameter", which has properties like "parameterId", "unit", "min", "max" and "name". This entity holds the metadata for a "parameterValue" object.

What I want to is to generate a viewmodel of all steps, which includes the "parameterValues". I also want to include the metadata from the "parameter" table, onto all "parameterValues". For matching "parameter" to "parameterValue", the property "parameterId" can be used.

So far I can get the list of steps with the included "parameterValues", by using Include, but I cant figure out how to merge in the "parameter" table...I have trived with .Join in the .Include statement, but that is not allowed.

I guess this usecase is common, but I cant wrap mye head around how to chain the lambda expression.

I would really appreciate some guidence.

Comment: Instead of describing all your entities, you should include the C# code here, it's much easier for us to understand what is happening

Comment: The weird part is that Include *is* what performs a join. Are you sure you don't just want `Include(x => x.SomeProperty).ThenInclude(y => y.ChildProperty)`?

Comment: There is no relation defined between parameterValues and parameters, so I can not use ThenInclude. I need to look up or join the parameter table and match with all parameterValues I think....? Im in transit now, and typing on my phone, it makes it hard to post actual code.